# Edit map legend properties from pause drawing screen ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend

Is there a way to edit a legend's properties from the Paused Drawing screen in ArcMap? The reason I ask is so I can update a legend's properties without having it redraw each time.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done by [toggling draft mode in the Layout window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-page-layouts.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_15D9DC291608405D900744EF68FD3190):

> When in draft mode, using Toggle Draft Mode, the contents of the page
>   elements are not drawn. Instead, only the bounding box of the frame
>   and a label showing its name are drawn. This makes it faster to work
>   with the page layout because you don't have to wait for the contents
>   of frames, especially data frames, to draw. You can control draft mode
>   for individual elements through the Frame tab of the element's
>   Properties dialog box.